# Getting Cannot find module 'http-backend-proxy' error e2e protractor

Tags: node.js, angular, protractor

I am getting `Error: Cannot find module 'http-backend-proxy'`.
But i have already installed this module?

What will be the possible solution for this error?

Comment: how did you installed it and how you are importing it? the module appears when you execute `npm list -g --depth=0`